# Set RGB value for label text

Tags: uilabel, rgb

I am having the color codes as R:38 G:171 B:228 , but when I set the values as .38f in the **color with Red : Green : Blue:**, I am unable to get the desired color:

```
[CategoryLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.38f green:.171f blue:.226f alpha:1.0f]];
```

Please help.

Comment: 31 isn't one of you the values you want, is it? Either you're setting it wrong - can you please show us exactly what you're doing including a code sample - or your display doesn't support precise enough colour for what you'd want I guess.

Comment: i am using the following code to set the textcolor for the label [CategoryLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.38f green:.171f blue:.226f alpha:1.0f]]; . Here the CategoryLbl is a label .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're mixing up two scales: UIColour looks like it uses floating point values 0-1 whereas the usual RGB values are 0-255. Instead you want

```
 38 / 255 = 0.1491f
171 / 255 = 0.6706f
226 / 255 = 0.8863f
```

so

```
[CategoryLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.1491f green:0.6706f blue:0.8863f alpha:1.0f]];
```

There may be better ways to do this, e.g. using the 0-255 values - I don't know OSX / iPhone development well.

Actually it looks like you can just do:

```
[CategoryLbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(38/255.f) green:(171/255.f) blue:(226/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
```

which is easier to understand (although I gave you enough d.p. the first one should be as accurate).

Comment: @developersaremad Don't forget to accept answers, if they worked for you.

Comment: @AleksejsMjaliks Okay sure :-)